# HTML syntax highlighting for unquoted attributes

Tags: html, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

Regardless whether it's a good approach or not:

Is there any way to make Sublime Text able to highlight HTML syntax for unquoted attributes? i.e

```
<div class=foo data-label=bar>
```

I have managed to fix the issue which causes unquoted `id` attributes to break the syntax across the document by following [these instructions](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8129).

However this still not allowing syntax highlighting for unquoted attributes which is what I am after.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow. Never heard of an HTML editor that didn't highlight unquoted attributes correctly. That's just sloppy, and like you said "regardless whether it's a good approach or not" it should have been there.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - The attribute names are highlighted fine, the problem is with unquoted attribute values.

Answer (score 5):

The reason unquoted attribute value syntax highlighting is not working is because Sublime is looking for a quoted string. Without quotes, none of the string regexes match. To work around this, you'll have to add a new scope `entity.other.attribute-value.html` that is included in `meta.tag`, begins matching at an `=`, matches `[0-9a-zA-Z-_]` one or more times, and stops matching at whitespace or `>`. You can then add this new scope to your color scheme and highlight it appropriately.

Comment: We're not sure how much attention the dev pays to it, but the community has set up [SublimeText/Issues](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues) on GitHub for stuff like this. Before reporting I'd verify that the same behavior still exists with the latest build of Sublime Text 3, as I know that some language issues (at least w/ Python) have been fixed along the way.

Comment: hey @MattDMo thanks for your answer, it seems pretty cool, can I achieve the same by editing the `HTML.tmLanguage` files as well? so the same runs across all my color schemes?

Comment: hey @BoltClock'saUnicorn, just in case you are wondering the same issue still happens on ST3 latest build including the bug which I found a workaround for the issue mentioned on the question's link.

Comment: @zanona yes, you would need to create the new scope with the regex I mentioned in `HTML.tmLanguage`, then create a new entry in your color scheme to highlight the new scope.

Comment: @MattDMo, that sounds great. I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/zanona/7858757) because I am not sure if I am doing the right things since it has no effect, perhaps I am just using the wrong rule? as you can see the `.tmLanguage` file implements `entity.other.attribute-value.html` and the color-scheme appends `entity.other.attribute-value` to the scope as well. If you could exemplify it would be great. thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that any attempt to make this happen would be inconsistent. Here's why:

```
<img src="whatever" alt="This is some text" class="something" />

<img src=whatever alt=This is some text class=something />

<img src=whatever alt=This is some text with > in it class=something />
```

See the way in which the second one is highlighted? Any regexp you put in is going to need to be able to tell not only the content of your text, but the *intent* of it, otherwise it won't be able to tell where the attribute value stops. Even here on SO, you and I both know how the second one *should* be highlighted, but the regexp fails to read it that way. And then there's the third one...

If you were to add a regexp to Sublime for this, odds are it would not highlight correctly. This is why text editors are programmed to look for enclosed strings; because when a string is surrounded by " marks, there's no guesswork as to where the string ends.

Comment: Thanks @DiMono, however notice that the spec defines valid, any unquoted attribute until a space character is found. In your example it's possible to see that `This` is the value assumed for the `alt` attribute and the following words `is some text` are defined as empty attributes instead (SO is correct here). I see a rule being possible whenever an unquoted attribute is defined it will stop its syntax highlighting when it is followed by a space character. So I believe it's possible indeed to create such rule as long as the user understands how and when to use unquoted attributes.

Comment: Or, and stay with me here, the user could make sure to always quote their attributes, because it's good form and won't break their code when it's out in the wild.

Comment: Possibly. However, this goes out of this question scope I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a good debate

Actually there are many tags with attributes with no values say

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly>
```

main point to notice is `readonly` this is valid HTML Syntax as attributes has no `=` nor any vales `values`

So subliming readonly is should not be there

So an additional efforts should be taken on account considering this too

Similarly for input we have one more such attrible `disabled`

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" disabled>
```

Lets try typing both in few ways and check how SO responds

```
<input type=text value=blah blab readonly>
```

Check second blah is marked red.

So this is sure that so I believe that attribute values with space should be quoted else editor or markup browser shell will consider it as other attribute.

attributes without values '=' are also considered.

But according to me

```
 <input type=text value=  blab readonly>
```

above value= should be sublimed as its an syntax error; Still SO is marking it as blue

At end one more try with

```
<input type=text value=   readonly>
```

See above again readonly is marked blue means its considering readonly as value for attribute but its actually an immediate after attribute & should be sublimed

Now how can you decide weather to sublime above or not

O/p of above is in figure
[image]

it means browser shell is interpreting it as value and not attribute and text box remains editable